# How do I deploy my AWS Secret Manager retrieval code in production with AWS CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-secrets-manager

I have written some code to retrieve my secrets from the AWS Secrets Manager to be used for further processing of other components. In my development environment I configured my credentials using AWS CLI. Once the code was compiled I am able to run it from VS and also from the exe that is generated.

Here is the code to connect to the secrets manager and retrieve the secrets

```
public static string Get(string secretName)
        {
            
            var config = new AmazonSecretsManagerConfig { RegionEndpoint = RegionEndpoint.USWest2 };
            
            IAmazonSecretsManager client = new AmazonSecretsManagerClient(config);
         
            var request = new GetSecretValueRequest
            {
                SecretId = secretName
            };

            GetSecretValueResponse response = null;
            try
            {
                response = Task.Run(async () => await client.GetSecretValueAsync(request)).Result;
            }
            catch (ResourceNotFoundException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The requested secret " + secretName + " was not found");
            }
            catch (InvalidRequestException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The request was invalid due to: " + e.Message);
            }
            catch (InvalidParameterException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The request had invalid params: " + e.Message);
            }

            return response?.SecretString;
        }
```

This code pulls credentials from the AWS CLI but when I try to run this code in another PC, it gives an IAM security error as expected, because it cannot figure out what the credentials are to connect to the secret manager.

What would be the best approach to deploy such a configuration in production? Would I need to install and configure AWS CLI in each and every deployment?

Comment: Full description is here - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-ec2.html

Answer (score 1):

If you're deploying the code in AWS you can use IAM Role, with a policy that allows getting secrets from Secret Manager, and attach this role in EC2 or ECS, etc

Comment: I will actually be deploying it on a non-AWS server. Any clue how to go about it?

Comment: @SourabhSriom What kind of server is this?

Comment: Its a Windows Server 2016

Comment: @SourabhSriom In this case, you will need to set up and configure AWS CLI in a "golden image", and start servers from this image. Or create a custom script that installs and configure AWS CLI that runs on the server startup.

Comment: so is the server deployed on premise somewhere or in a different cloud?

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a corporate environment with existing authentication infrastructure in place, you probably want to look at [identity federation](https://aws.amazon.com/identity/federation/) solutions to use with AWS.