# How to use AWS CLI secrets with IIS in production?

Tags: amazon-web-services, iis

This is my question (literally stolen from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63402086/3845390), but the ultimate question is different)

"I have written some code to retrieve my secrets from the AWS Secrets Manager to be used for further processing of other components. In my development environment I configured my credentials using AWS CLI. Once the code was compiled I am able to run it from VS and also from the exe that is generated."

My question is that once it's on my IIS production server, I repeat these steps but it doesn't work, because I run the steps as the user account I'm logged in as, but the IIS process doesn't run as the logged in user, so the code can't get what it needs.

I want the IIS process to be able to access these credentials under its own user profile. How do I place the credentials under that profile? [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25560545/3845390) seems to have the answer (`C:\Users\<IIS_app_name>\.aws\credentials`) but how do I actually access the `<IIS_app_name>`? Or figure out what it is? I attempt to access this path with my II_app_name, but I get an error that it doesn't exist.

This is an on prem server that accesses aws secrets manager.

Comment: How the credentials are stored depends on the method you choose, file, database, AWS/Azure key storage, web.config/app.settings file, Bit buckets key storage, etc.

Comment: @YurongDai - that's what the docs all say. What more information do I need to provide to get a helpful answer?

Comment: Maybe you need to get professional AWS product technical support : https://aws.amazon.com/cn/contact-us/?cmpid=docs_headercta_contactus